# rotations, covering groups and a conjecture

Tags: matrices, group-theory, representation-theory, classical-mechanics

I'm in search of some order and clarity. (There might be some errors )

I'm reading a good old text most of you probably read in your youth.

I am reading about Q matrices $Q_{\psi} , Q_{\theta}, Q_{\phi}$.

It is known that an orthogonal matrix can be written in terms of a homomorphic Q matrix.

For example $Q_{\phi}$ for rotation about  z is

$ \begin{pmatrix}
     \cos{\frac{\phi}{2} + i \sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}} & 0\\ 
     0 & \cos{\frac{\phi}{2} - i \sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}}
 \end{pmatrix} $

from

$ \begin{pmatrix}
     \cos{\phi} & \sin{\phi} & 0\\ 
     - \sin{\phi} & \cos{\phi} & 0\\
     0 & 0 & 1 
 \end{pmatrix} $

The process for doing this is well known, and I can add it here if requested but I don't know if it will add anything useful to anyone.

$P$ and $Q$ are then derivable using the standard techniques.

I am now going to ask a question. Before I do I am now working under the assumption that this is one instance of the whole SU(2) double cover of SO(3) thing.

It seems to me that it will be possible to find a whole lot of these covering groups and to even make a claim like every group has a covering group without even thinking too hard.

For sure every lie group should. I am making these statements based on one observation.

Now that such a  statement has been made, it would seem that a word proof is in order, I don't see a computational proof covering all the cases.

How does one prove or refute my statement about the existence of covering groups for every group?

Comment: (Because some keywords are missing:) You are speaking of the unit sphere in the quaternions covering $SO(3)\in M_3(\Bbb R)$ and representing the quaternions via Pauli matrices, getting an equivalence to $SU(2)\in M_2(\Bbb C)$.

Comment: Please be less self-deprecating! It becomes irritating after a while!

Comment: I have now made the post less self-deprecating.

Comment: Every Lie group $G$ has a universal cover $\widetilde{G}$ (unique up to isomorphism) which contains a copy of the fundamental group $\pi_1(G)$ as a discrete central subgroup such that $\widetilde{G}/\pi_1(G)\cong G$. Any covering homomorphism onto $G$ is equivalent to a projection $\widetilde{G}/K\to\widetilde{G}/\pi(G)$ for some subgroup $K\subseteq\pi_1(G)$. The universal cover $\widetilde{G}$ is maximal: it cannot be covered (nontrivially) and covers all other covers of $G$. (Also, the class of all Lie groups with the same Lie algebra as $G$ is precisely $\widetilde{G}$ and its quotients.)

Comment: @runway44 What is the universal cover of $SU(2)$? Even if that's trivial for an expert it might be interesting to see it as a concrete example.

Comment: @KurtG. As $SU(2)$ is topologically a $3$-sphere (which is a good textbook exercise), it is already simply connected. That is, it is its own universal cover.